# Append value to list inside a column manipulates all rows instead of one

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Dataframe:

```
    text                 values 
0  a text               []
1  another text         []
2  some more text       []
3  and again some text  []
```

I want to append items to a specific list by index. For example I want to add "value" to the first row.
However when I do `df.iloc[0]['values'].append("value")`, "value" is added to every list in the column values:

```
        text                 values 
0  a text               ["value"]
1  another text         ["value"]
2  some more text       ["value"]
3  and again some text  ["value"]
```

I also tried `df['values'].iloc[0].append("value")`, same result. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: IIUC, `df.iloc[0, 1] = ['text']` for the first value then `df.iloc[0,1].append('value')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to the fact that values within the 'values' column always refer to the same object. Look at the following example:

```
import pandas as pd

lst = []
df = pd.DataFrame({'values': [[] for i in range(5)]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'values': [lst for i in range(5)]})

df.iloc[0]['values'].append(3)
df2.iloc[0]['values'].append(3)
```

Let's now print the content of these two dataframes:

```
>>> df
  values
0    [3]
1     []
2     []
3     []
4     []

>>> df2
  values
0    [3]
1    [3]
2    [3]
3    [3]
4    [3]
```

If I was you I would dig into your code and check if those values always refer to the same object.